# How to Setup a printer over a Speedport router (Telekom)

Tags: wireless, printing, router, cups-lpd

Since I moved to the German Telekom as provider I have not been able up to now to print over WLAN through my home printer. I find nearly no help in the manual of my router (a Speedport W724 V type B).

Comment: I am asking myself, if Askubuntu is  the right place for this question. Look: since I got my Speedport - July 2015 - there has been NO QUESTION here tagged speedport - although my former ability to print over WLAN was lost on the change, and millions of people in Germany do have a Speedport (and I guess thousends thereof working with Linux). Is there perhaps here around a more appropriate community for it?

Answer (score 0):

**GUI/Ubuntu** - After successful setup on my Kubuntu desktop, here is an answer for Kubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. (But look at the end for a general CUPS solution!)

- Activate the printer and connect it by USB with the Speedport.
- Essential step: search in the Kubuntu menu for a "printer" program, then install the printer manager and start it.

  (using CLI: sudo system-config-printer & )
- In the printer manager GUI, select add,printer, network  printer, Find, which adds a device named (in my case) JetDirect(speedport.ip)(192.168.2.1) and finds a port number port=9100

Go on with: forward,HP,Officejet6210, name= Net-HP-OfficeJet6200, ok.
Here as entered for my old HP from 2005. But the decisive advantage of system-config-printer over what I had tested before lays in the "find" step.

**CUPS/Linux** - In the Printer Manager double click on the icon of your new crated printer. I get "Device URI=socket://speedport.ip:9100",

which is exactly  the net address of the printer for entering in CUPS (in your browser, over the URL=http://localhost:631/).

Whith this information you can setup and manage **any** printer type using CUPS alone. And this should work also outside Kubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This info works:

1. Go to http://localhost:631/
2. Add a printer
3. Select your printer model
4. Select the option **AppSocket** and use `socket://speedport.ip:9100`